# Create new dataframe column keeping the first value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiplication

I have a dataframe with two columns

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['A'] = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
df['B'] = [1.66, 1.66, 1.66, 1.66, 1.66]
```

```
  A    B
0.1 1.66
0.1 1.66
0.1 1.66
0.1 1.66
0.1 1.66
```

I want to create a new column where I hold the first value of column `A` and then complete the rest of column values as following:

```
  A     B          C
0.1  1.66       A[0]
0.1  1.66  B[0]*C[0]
0.1  1.66  B[1]*C[1]
0.1  1.66  B[2]*C[2]
0.1  1.66  B[3]*C[3]
```

staying this way

```
   A   B       C
1.66 0.1     0.1
1.66 0.1   0.166
1.66 0.1 0.27556
1.66 0.1 0.45743
1.66 0.1 0.75933
```

Is there any way to achieve this? ...
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df["C"] = df["B"].shift().fillna(df.loc[0, "A"]).cumprod()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you don't have a large df

```
data = {'A' : [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
'B' : [1.66, 1.66, 1.66, 1.66, 1.66]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.at[0, 'C'] = df.iloc[0]['A']
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df.at[i, 'C'] = df.iloc[i-1]['B'] * df.iloc[i-1]['C']
df
```